# How to stagger photos in a grid?

Tags: html, css, blogger, photo

This a very simple question but I can't seem to get the coding right. How do you create a 6 picture photo grid like the one on here http://innisfree-template.blogspot.ca/ ? I don't need the text block in the middle, just need to know how to stagger the photos like this.

Comment: You can use tables (heavily discouraged) or any grid system you want. For maximum responsiveness, you could use **[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)** framework or if you want to use a grid system only then you can use **[960 Grid System](https://960.gs/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use flexbox or css grid layout instead of using bulky frameworks just for a simple grid. Try to avoid them for simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use a jquery library like [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) to achieve that type of grid. Using javascript all the boxes will riarrange dinamically if you change them in the future.